# qt prevent QLineEdit getting expanded in Layout

Tags: qt

I have a question about `QLineEdit` stuff. I created a `QVBoxLayout` element and using `addWidget(widget)` to add some `QLabel` or `QComboBox` to the layout. Most of them works fine except `QLineEdit` as you can see in the images I posted. `QLineEdit` just take half space of whole window. My question is how to prevent this? (I am pretty sure it is the problem of `QLineEdit` because tested them all by removing each widget, without `QLineEdit` I will get something like first image)

these are code for adding `QLineEdit`.

```
m_qtLeftValue = new QLineEdit;
m_qtLeftValue->setText(m_leftValue.c_str());
m_qtLeftValue->setFixedWidth( 20 );
m_sidePaneLayout->addWidget(m_qtLeftValue, 4, 0, 1, 1);
```

where `m_sidePaneLayout` is defined as this:

```
// add sidePane to UI
QWidget *sidePaneWidgetHolder = new QWidget(this);
m_sidePaneLayout = new QGridLayout(sidePaneWidgetHolder);

// add to m_gridLayout
m_gridLayout->addWidget(sidePaneWidgetHolder, 0, 3, 9, 1);
```

hoping anyone can help me with this question, thanks !

[image: result that I want]
[image: result that I DO NOT want]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your `sidePaneWidgetHolder` a custom class derived from `QWidget` and override it's [`sizeHint()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#sizeHint-prop) to return a reasonable default, and [set a `sizePolicy`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop) on it - You'll probably want [`QSizePolicy::Maximum`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qsizepolicy.html#Policy-enum) for as vertical policy.